# 2016 Gap and Island question - combine rows to create groups within ranges

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Using Microsoft SQL Server 2016:

Having sample data in table @A:

```
Declare @A Table (Col varchar(20), DateIn date)
Insert @A Select 'DEF', '10/27/2023'
Insert @A Select 'DEF', '10/28/2023'
Insert @A Select 'DEF', '10/29/2023'
Insert @A Select 'DEF', '10/30/2023'
Insert @A Select 'DEF', '10/31/2023'

Insert @A Select 'ABC', '10/27/2023'
Insert @A Select 'ABC', '10/28/2023'
Insert @A Select 'ABC', '10/29/2023'
Insert @A Select 'ABC', '10/30/2023'
Insert @A Select 'ABC', '10/31/2023'
Insert @A Select 'ABC', '11/01/2023'
Insert @A Select 'ABC', '11/02/2023'
Insert @A Select 'ABC', '11/03/2023'
Insert @A Select 'ABC', '11/04/2023'

Insert @A Select 'XXX', '10/31/2023'
Insert @A Select 'XXX', '11/01/2023'
Insert @A Select 'XXX', '11/02/2023'
```

The desired output would look like what is in table @B:

```
Declare @B Table (Col varchar(20), DateIn date, DateOut date, DaysIn int)
Insert @B Select 'DEF', '10/27/2023', '10/30/2023', 4
Insert @B Select 'ABC', '10/27/2023', '10/30/2023', 4
Insert @B Select 'DEF', '10/31/2023', '10/31/2023', 1
Insert @B Select 'ABC', '10/31/2023', '10/31/2023', 1
Insert @B Select 'XXX', '10/31/2023', '10/31/2023', 1
Insert @B Select 'ABC', '11/01/2023', '11/02/2023', 2
Insert @B Select 'XXX', '11/01/2023', '11/02/2023', 2
Insert @B Select 'ABC', '11/03/2023', '11/04/2023', 2
```

I need to find longest matching date ranges within the data found in Col (table @A). For example DEF, ABC and XXX all have a of date 10/31/2023, but XXX does not have any dates before 10/31/2023, so the first possible DateIn in the output for XXX would be 10/31/2023; it can't be contained in the range 10/27/2023 - 10/30/2023.

I am currently working on a solution which requires two (2) while loops of the base table.
I have looked at several StackOverflow questions, I can't find the right solution.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsql-server%5D+gaps+and+islands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without joins:

```
WITH NumOfCols
AS
(
   SELECT Col, DateIn
      ,COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY DateIN) AS NumCols
   FROM @A
)
,Boundaries
AS
(
   SELECT Col, DateIn
      ,CASE WHEN LAG(NumCols) OVER (ORDER BY DateIn) <> NumCols THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Boundary
   FROM NumOfCols
)
,Grps
AS
(
   SELECT Col, DateIn
      ,SUM(Boundary) OVER (ORDER BY DateIn) AS Grp
   FROM Boundaries
)
SELECT Col
   ,MIN(DateIn) AS DateIn
   ,MAX(DateIn) AS DateOut
   ,DATEDIFF(day, MIN(DateIn), MAX(DateIn)) + 1 AS DaysIn
FROM Grps
GROUP BY Col, Grp;
```

Comment: Brilliant, thank you so much. It is 100% perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting little problem. You can do:

```
select c.col, y.mind, y.maxd, 1 + datediff(day, y.mind, y.maxd) as days
from (
  select concat('/', k, '/') as j, min(d) as mind, max(d) as maxd
  from (
    select d.d, string_agg(col, '/') within group (order by col) as k
    from (select distinct date_in as d from t) d
    join t on t.date_in = d.d
    group by d.d
  ) x
  group by k
) y
join (select distinct col from t) c on y.j like concat('%/', c.col, '/%')
order by y.mind, c.col
```

Result:

```
 col  mind        maxd        days 
 ---- ----------- ----------- ---- 
 ABC  2023-10-27  2023-10-30  4    
 DEF  2023-10-27  2023-10-30  4    
 ABC  2023-10-31  2023-10-31  1    
 DEF  2023-10-31  2023-10-31  1    
 XXX  2023-10-31  2023-10-31  1    
 ABC  2023-11-01  2023-11-02  2    
 XXX  2023-11-01  2023-11-02  2    
 ABC  2023-11-03  2023-11-04  2
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/doI0K7Jl).

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. I unfortunately can't run the script as it uses the function string_agg which hasn't been introduced yet in my version SQL Server.

Comment: @T-Rex Prior to 2017 there was a workaround for `string_agg()` using XML/Paths. I never really learned since it was becoming rapidly obsolete. I guess I was wrong. Anyway, you can search for it and change the query accordingly.